# How to set a default namespace in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to know if helm has a option similar to `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace test-namespace`, So I wouldn't have to pass namespace every time.

Comment: It should honor the default namespace as in that `kubectl config set-context` command.

Answer (score 0):

The helm tool is used to deploy modeled kubernetes resource packages. So **under the hood, helm uses go-template and kubectl** and outside of the helm argument definition **"-n"** it necessarily refers to the current namespace.

By default (i.e. without using the **"-n"** option of the helm cli), the helm version will be deployed in the current namespace.

So you can ignore this option if you are in the right namespace with the commands :

```yaml
kubens test-namespace # Install by krew plugin or binary release
```

OR

```yaml
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace test-namespace # kubectl native subcommand
```

OR

```yaml
kubie ns test-namespace # (recommended) Install by binary release or rust cargo
```